# DbProviderFactory code relationship with code for creating a SqlConnection in ADO.Net

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection

When I instantiate a SqlConnection object in ADO.Net, then does this code result in the execution of corresponding DbProviderFactory code ? So when the code in block 2 is executed by, then we actually end up executing code in block 1. **But I am not sure if this is true.**

**CODE BLOCK 1 - Instantiate a SqlConnection using DbProviderFactory approach**

```
DbProviderFactory factory =
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

**CODE BLOCK 2 -Instantiate a SqlConnection using standard ADO.Net code**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is.  Are you asking if the IL produced (when reflected) actually looks like BLOCK 1?

Comment: Not the IL. I meant, if behind-the-scenes, the code that actually gets executed is the corresponding DbFactory code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at some *.net Framework assemblies* and found the following

`DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName)` will return an Factory object according to the *given providerName*.
Let's assume *providerName indicates an SQL Provider* so we will get an `SqlClientFactory`.

Afterwards `factory.CreateConnection()` will be called. In this case `SqlClientFactory.CreateConnection()` will be called which is implemented as

```
public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection();
}
```

I think the **answer to your question** is that calling the **factory methods will call the methods of the provider specific classes** and not the other way round!

Comment: I am trying to go through the decompiled code for SqlConnection and it seems that any call to SqlConnection will cause the DbPRoviderFactory to be created. So behind-the-scene, it may be that DbProvider classes are called. But still not sure.

Comment: I don't think so. Within static ctor of SqlConnection there is a SqlConnectionFactory but i can't see a code line of an instance related code within sqlConnection that makes a call to _connectionFactory. Anyway as SqlClientFactory calls the constructor of SqlConnection it would be an endless selfcall if SqlConnection calls SqlClientFactory within!

Comment: Isn't the _connectionFactory doing something in the SqlConnection constructor? This factory is an instance of DbProviderFactory. Does that mean DbProvider factory is somehow being used?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As SqlClientFactory.CreateConnection creates a new SqlConnection the static ctor of SqlConnection is called at this point. So if within SqlConnection a Factory would create another SqlConnection ... this does not sound very logical to me

Answer (score 3):

To be sure what's going on, consider removing code block 2 - it isn't needed and adds complexity. Just use the factories capabilities to use the connection. For example, you have:

```
DbProviderFactory factory =
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

Add the following :

```
try
{
  connection.Open();
  var command = connection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
  (..etc...)
```

We had to connect to MS SQL or Oracle, depending on user preference and this worked perfectly for us, the only thing unique will be the provider, connection string, and command text. Microsoft shows an example how to pull the providers from machine.config [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope this helps, and if I'm incorrect, please let me know!